# How to identify an instance of multidimensional object in java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, instanceof

Is there any alternative way to identify instance of multidimensional object without hardcode on it?

```
//source
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static <T> boolean isPrimitiveWrapper(T p_obj) throws Exception {
        if (Number.class.isInstance(p_obj) || Number[].class.isInstance(p_obj)) {
            return true;
        } else if (Boolean.class.isInstance(p_obj) || Boolean[].class.isInstance(p_obj)) {
            return true;
        } else if (Character.class.isInstance(p_obj) || Character[].class.isInstance(p_obj)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Integer[][][] a = {{{0}}, {{1}}, {{0}}};

        println(isPrimitiveWrapper(a));
        println(isPrimitiveWrapper(a[0]));
        println(isPrimitiveWrapper(a[0][0]));
        println(isPrimitiveWrapper(a[0][0][0]));
    }

    public static <T> void println(T p_t) {
        System.out.println(p_t);
    }

}

//Actual Result
false
false
true
true

//Expected Result
true
true
true
true
```

Based on the example above, we have no problem to deal with non-array & single dimension array object, but it is fail to identify multidimensional array object.

It is too ugly to hardcode the number of dimension.

Comment: How do you define "a primitive wrapper"? It's unclear what is hiding exactly behind this concept of yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test {

    public static <T> boolean isPrimitiveWrapper(T p_obj) throws Exception {
        return isPrimitiveWrapper(p_obj.getClass());
    }

    public static boolean isPrimitiveWrapper(Class p_obj) throws Exception {
        if (Number.class.isAssignableFrom(p_obj)) {
            return true;
        } else if (Boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(p_obj)) {
            return true;
        } else if (Character.class.isAssignableFrom(p_obj)) {
            return true;
        } else if (p_obj.isArray()) {

            //To handle multi dimension array
            while (p_obj.isArray()) {
                p_obj = p_obj.getComponentType();
            }

            return isPrimitiveWrapper(p_obj);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isPrimitiveWrapper(boolean p_obj) {
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isPrimitiveWrapper(byte p_obj) {
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isPrimitiveWrapper(short p_obj) {
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isPrimitiveWrapper(float p_obj) {
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isPrimitiveWrapper(int p_obj) {
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isPrimitiveWrapper(long p_obj) {
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isPrimitiveWrapper(char p_obj) {
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isPrimitiveWrapper(double p_obj) {
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Integer[][][] a = {{{0}}, {{1}}, {{0}}};
        int[][][] b = {{{0}}, {{1}}, {{0}}};

        println(isPrimitiveWrapper(a));
        println(isPrimitiveWrapper(a[0]));
        println(isPrimitiveWrapper(a[0][0]));
        println(isPrimitiveWrapper(a[0][0][0]));

        println(isPrimitiveWrapper(b));
        println(isPrimitiveWrapper(b[0]));
        println(isPrimitiveWrapper(b[0][0]));
        println(isPrimitiveWrapper(b[0][0][0]));
    }

    public static <T> void println(T p_t) {
        System.out.println(p_t);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard way to determine, if the class itself is wrapper for primitive type or not, so, you can do something like this:

```
private static final Set <Class <?>> primitiveWrappers;

static {
    Set <Class <?>> tmp = new HashSet<>();
    tmp.add (Integer.class);
    tmp.add (Boolean.class);
    tmp.add (Character.class);
    tmp.add (Long.class);
    tmp.add (Double.class);
    tmp.add (Float.class);
    // ... have I forgotten smth?
    primitiveWrappers = Collections.unmodifiableSet(tmp);
}

private static boolean isPrimitiveWrapperOrArrayOf(Object o) {
    if (o.getClass().isArray())
        return isPrimitiveWrapperOrArrayOf(o.getClass().getComponentType());
    else
        return primitiveWrappers.contains(o.getClass());
}
```

When you run `isPrimitiveWrapperOrArrayOf`, the class is being checked if it's array, if it is, we'll check it's component type (for example, that would be Integer[] for Integer[][]) in the same function `isPrimitiveWrapperOrArrayOf`, so this way we'll come to just `SomeClass`, which will be checked if it's contained inside hardcoded `primitiveWrappers`

By the way, you may take a look at Commons Lang, [`ClassUtils.wrapperToPrimitive`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ClassUtils.html#wrapperToPrimitive(java.lang.Class)) may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. I guess that's what you want.
But this code looks like some sort of a hack anyway
(which is not necessarily bad).

```
private static boolean isPrimitiveWrapper(Object obj){
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        String cls = obj.getClass().getCanonicalName();
        return "java.lang.Integer".equals(cls) || 
               cls.startsWith("java.lang.Integer[]");
    }
}
```

Here is another hack. Both codes should work OK though.

```
private static boolean isPrimitiveWrapper(Object obj){
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        String cls = obj.getClass().getName();
        cls = cls.replaceAll(";", "");
        return cls.matches("\\[*L?java\\.lang\\.Integer");
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider `IntegerUtils`

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Yeah, I've just considered it.

Comment: What about instances of `mypackage.MyFooBarInteger` ?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Try them.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt did you mean `mypackage.Integer`? Only this will break the first approach.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Thanks. You're right. Fixed that too now, I think.